# Change a PHP array into a Smarty Array and read results in template

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, smarty, prestashop

I'm busy with Prestashop. Unfortunenately I never worked before with Smarty. I have the following question: How can I change the PHP array assign into a Smarty Array and how can I read it out in my template with Smarty?

```
$query="SELECT id_category, id_parent FROM ps_category ORDER BY id_category ASC, id_parent ASC"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);

while (list($hlc_id_category, $hlc_id_parent) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
   {
   $query="SELECT name, description FROM ps_category_lang WHERE id_category = '" . $hlc_id_category . "'";

   $resultnaam = mysql_query($query);
   list($hlc_categoryname, $hlc_description) = mysql_fetch_row($resultnaam);

   if ($hlc_id_parent == 2)
  {
  $hlc_category_class = 'hoofdcategorie';
  }

  if ($hlc_id_parent > 2)
  {
  $hlc_category_class = 'hoofdcategorie';
  }

$hlc_categories[] = array ('hlc_id_category' => $hlc_id_category, 'hlc_categoryname' => $hlc_categoryname, 'hlc_description' => $hlc_description);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `mysql` API? It's no longer supported and there are better alternatives.

Comment: Which alternatives can you recommend me?

Comment: Besides the fact that you should avoid the `mysql` API (look into `PDO`), why are you even using an API for the database? Prestashop provides the `DB` class to run your queries.

Comment: Yes I know, like I said, i'm new with Prestashop and Smarty. If I have the solution for my array problem is the next step to use the DB class.

Comment: @Dinizworld: `PDO` and `mysqli` (mysql improved) are good alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi first assign the variable to the template

```
$smarty->assign('hlc_categories', $hlc_categories);
```

Then in your template file loop through it like this

```
{section name=inst loop=$hlc_categories}
    {$hlc_categories[inst].hlc_id_category}
    {$hlc_categories[inst].hlc_categoryname}
{/section}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use :

```
$smarty->assign('categories', $hlc_categories);
```

Within the template :

```
{foreach from=$categories item=category}
    {$category.hlc_id_category}
    {$category.hlc_categoryname}
    {$category.hlc_description}
{/foreach}
```